# How high will the rocket go?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, projectile-motion

A certain​ rocket, initially at​ rest, is shot straight up with an acceleration of 12t meters per second during the first 77 seconds after​ blast-off after which the engine cuts out and the rocket is subject only to gravitational acceleration of −10 meters per second.  How high will the rocket​ go?

Comment: Hint: Use kinematic equations, namely $y_{max}=\frac{2v_0sin^2\theta}{g}$

Comment: @泥九奈加 i havent been though this, but i have 15 minutes left to submit this. Would g be gravitational pull? how would i figure out what theta is?

Comment: @Will Njundong: $\theta = \pi/2$, $v_{0} = 0$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Without more context for your question, it looks a lot like you’re simply looking for a last-minute solution to a homework problem, which is not the purpose of this site and is not going to get you much in the way of answers.

Comment: @amd well time's up to submit that, but I'd still like to know how to do it. I tried using gravitational acceleration to set up differential equation for the rocket before it gets into freefall, and I think I was supposed to figure out where velocity is zero for the max height, but that's where i got stuck

Comment: If the rocket goes straight up and down, once you’ve figured out the altitude and velocity at engine shutdown, the easiest way to compute how much farther it climbs is via conservation of energy. It will start falling at the point that its kinetic energy becomes zero.